# Java load properties file java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have one properties file, name is `XYZ.properties`. I want to get details from this file.
My property file location is `D:\properties_file\XYZ.properties`

For this i am using below code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class LoadProp {
    private static Properties prop = new Properties();
    public static Properties getProperties() throws Exception {
        if (prop.isEmpty()) {
            InputStream fis = LoadProp.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\\properties_file\\XYZ.properties");
            prop.load(fis);
        }
        return prop;
    }
}

public class demo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Properties propFile;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            propFile = LoadProp.getProperties();
            System.out.println(propFile.getProperty(Constants.URL));
        }
        catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run this on `prop.load(fis)` line it gives me the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Resources are not files, do not reside in the file system, do not have backslashes as directory separators, and do not have drive letters as part of their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
InputStream fis = LoadProp.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\\properties_file\\XYZ.properties");
```

to

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\properties_file\\XYZ.properties");
```

The `getResourceAsStream` is designed to read a resource from classpath (resource inside your app), in order to read file that is outside the app, use java File API.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.getResourceAsStream` does not open a file system location. It tries to find the resource in the class path. You may want to read the properties with a `FileInputStream` instead.